# Subir archivos grandes sin afectar el rendimiento - LaravelApi

Tags: laravel

Estoy subiendo archivos de más de 50MB, mi problema esque siempre se presenta un problema de tiempo excedido incluso utilizando

```
post_max_size = 500M;
memory_limit = 500M;
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

el problema continua.

Actualmente mi cotigo se encuentra de la siguiente manera.

```
$file   = $request->file('video');
$video  = Storage::disk('public')->put('/trainer/curse/' . $request->curse_id, $file);
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo subir archivos grandes?

Answer (score 0):

solo debes colocar al incio de tu script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0'); // no hay un tiempo limite
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 segundos = 5 minutes
```

si deseas configurarlo en tu `php.ini` debes buscar:

```
max_execution_time=300
```

Comment: No es necesario manipular el `php.ini` es un hack muy  común. Creo que hay mejores posibilidades que trabajar alterando la memoria.

Comment: @DoubleM si es lo que consideras que es lo mejor ps adelante pero asi tengas 45G de memoria y la conexion del usuario es lenta marcara max execution time :D saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No sé si lo hiciste ya que los parámetros que mencionas deberían de funcionar pero recuerda que para que los cambios en el `php.ini` surtan efecto debes de reiniciar Apache, y para comprobar que los cambios SI están siendo tomados, puedes ejecutar un `phpinfo();` y checar que los parámetros sean los correctos.

Por otro lado, puedes lograr un mejor rendimiento al subir archivos pesados haciendo "streams", como lo siguiente:

```
$file = $request->file('video');
$disco = Storage::disk('public');
$video = $disco->put('/trainer/curse/' . $request->curse_id, fopen($file, 'r+'));
```

De esta manera PHP solo requerirá unos pocos MB de RAM incluso si tratas de subir archivos de varios GB.